# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL --- When including PHP into JQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to upload dynamic content into a Modal Window through the use of a targeted PHP document and a JavaScript function that generates a modal window through the use of inputs. When I include the PHP there is an error with characters in the HTML that are causing the program to goof.

Here's what I'm using:

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $('#ContactUs').ModalWindow({
        height: '70%',
        width: '750px',
        title: 'Does This Work?',
        description: <?php echo "'"; include './php/ContactUs.php'; echo "'"; ?>,
    });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require '/DBConnect.php';
        echo '<div class="contactUsWindow" id="contactUsWindow">';      
        echo '<table class="employeeContactTable"><tr>';

        $findDepartments = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT DISTINCT Department FROM company_contact");
        while($departments = mysqli_fetch_array($findDepartments))
        {
            $department = $departments['Department'];
            echo '<td><table class="departmentTable"><tr><td><table class="departmentTableColumn">';        
            $findContacts = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM company_contact WHERE Department = '" . $department . "' ORDER BY Sub_Department DESC");
            $numberOfContacts = $findContacts->num_rows; 
            $contactCounter = 1;
            $numberOfContactsPerColumn = 2;

            while($contacts = mysqli_fetch_array($findContacts))
            {
                $firstName = $contacts['First_Name'];
                $lastName = $contacts['Last_Name'];
                $phoneNumber = $contacts['Phone_Number'];
                $email = $contacts['Email'] . '<span style="font-family:sans-serif">@</span>racecabinet.com';
                $subDepartment = $contacts['Sub_Department'];
                $imgLocation = $contacts['Picture_Reference_Location'];
                $imgPath = "/PictureLibrary/EmployeeHeadshots/" . $imgLocation;

                if ($contactCounter % $numberOfContactsPerColumn != 0)
                {
                    if ($contactCounter != $numberOfContacts)
                    {
                        echo '<tr> <td> <table class="employee"> <tr> <td> <img src="' . $imgPath . '">  </td> <td> <table class="employeeInfo"> <tr><td><b>' . $firstName . ' ' . $lastName .  ' </b></td></tr><tr><td>' . $department . ' - ' . $subDepartment . '</td></tr><tr><td> Email: ' . $email . ' </td></tr><tr><td> Phone: ' . $phoneNumber . '</td></tr></table></td></table></td></tr>';

                    }
                    else if ($contactCounter == $numberOfContacts)
                    {
                        echo '<tr> <td> <table class="employee"> <tr> <td> <img src="' . $imgPath . '">  </td> <td> <table class="employeeInfo"> <tr><td><b>' . $firstName . ' ' . $lastName .  ' </b></td></tr><tr><td>' . $department . ' - ' . $subDepartment . '</td></tr><tr><td> Email: ' . $email . ' </td></tr><tr><td> Phone: ' . $phoneNumber . '</td></tr></table></td></table></td></tr></table></td>';
                    }
                }
                else if ($contactCounter % $numberOfContactsPerColumn == 0)
                {
                    if ($contactCounter != $numberOfContacts)
                    {
                        echo '<tr> <td> <table class="employee"> <tr> <td> <img src="' . $imgPath . '">  </td> <td> <table class="employeeInfo"> <tr><td><b>' . $firstName . ' ' . $lastName .  ' </b></td></tr><tr><td>' . $department . ' - ' . $subDepartment . '</td></tr><tr><td> Email: ' . $email . ' </td></tr><tr><td> Phone: ' . $phoneNumber . '</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td><td><table class="departmentTableColumn">';
                    }
                    else if ($contactCounter == $numberOfContacts)
                    {
                        echo '<tr> <td> <table class="employee"> <tr> <td> <img src="' . $imgPath . '">  </td> <td> <table class="employeeInfo"> <tr><td><b>' . $firstName . ' ' . $lastName .  ' </b></td></tr><tr><td>' . $department . ' - ' . $subDepartment . '</td></tr><tr><td> Email: ' . $email . ' </td></tr><tr><td> Phone: ' . $phoneNumber . '</td></tr></table></td></table></td></tr></table></td>';
                    }                           
                }
                $contactCounter += 1;
            }
        }
        echo '</tr></table></table></div>';
    ?>
```

Modal Window:

```
(function($){
    // Defining our jQuery plugin

$.fn.ModalWindow = function(prop){

    // Default parameters

    var options = $.extend({
        height : "70%",
        width : "750px",
        title:"Hey James isn't this slick?",
        description: "This is where we put the stuff that does the things.",
    },prop);

    return this.click(function(e){
        add_block_page();
        add_popup_box();
        add_styles();

        $('.ModalWindow').fadeIn();
    });

     function add_styles(){ 
                    /*Block page overlay*/

        $('.ModalWindow').css({ 
            'position':'relative',
            'display':'none',
            'margin': '7.5% auto auto auto',
            'height': options.height,
            'width': options.width,
            'max-width': '100%',
            'border':'1px solid #fff',
            'box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
            '-moz-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
            '-webkit-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
            'border-radius':'10px',
            '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
            '-webkit-border-radius':'10px',
            'background': '#f2f2f2', 
            'z-index':'50',
        });
        $('.ModalClose').css({
            'position':'relative',
            'top':'0px',
            'left':'0px',
            'float':'right',
            'display':'block',
            'height':'30px',
            'width':'30px',
            'background': 'url(/PictureLibrary/ModalWindowImages/CloseButton.png) no-repeat',
        });

        $('.BlockPage').css({
            'position':'fixed',
            'top':'0',
            'left':'0',
            'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
            'height': '100%',
            'width': '100%',
            'z-index':'20'
        });
        $('.InnerModalWindow').css({
            'background-color':'#fff',
            'height': 'calc(100% - 50px)',
            'height': '-moz-calc(100% - 50px)',
            'height': '-webkit-calc(100% - 50px)',
            'width': 'calc(100% - 50px)',
            'width': '-moz-calc(100% - 50px)',
            'width': '-webkit-calc(100% - 50px)',
            'padding':'10px',
            'margin':'15px',
            'border-radius':'10px',
            '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
            '-webkit-border-radius':'10px',
            'overflow-x':'auto',
            'overflow-y':'auto'
        });
    }

     function add_block_page(){
        var block_page = $('<div class="BlockPage"></div>');

        $(block_page).appendTo('body');
    }

     function add_popup_box(){
         var pop_up = $('<div class="ModalWindow"><a href="#" class="ModalClose"></a><div class="InnerModalWindow"><h2>' + options.title + '</h2>' + options.description + '</div></div>');
         $(pop_up).appendTo('.BlockPage');

         $('.ModalClose').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().fadeOut().remove();
            $('.BlockPage').fadeOut().remove();              
         });
    }

    return this;
};

})(jQuery);
```

I know that the 'Contact Us' page and the modal window both render correctly on their own, but when I try to use them together the resulting code is having problems with the quotation marks, that are causing the description to not be read as one large string.

Comment: What's the generated HTML source? It'll be easier to debug this with it. Also, I notice a syntax error: you have two `});` after the description.

Comment: you are mixing severside and client side code, this would not work

Comment: @meda: it will work, I've done this before. There is probably something that closes the string, causing a syntax error. We need to see the HTML source to know.

Comment: Look at the final generated HTML/javascript code in the browser - you may want to post it here - it'll be much easier to debug.

Comment: It could be an invisible _char_.  It e.g. happens to me sometimes when writing to fast and hitting `space` while I still hold the `alt` key. So if you haven't done already, enable the options in your editor that shows invisible chars and check if there is one at the line the error message tells you.

Comment: @LéoLam maybe, but still poor way to get data from PHP, maybe ajax call is more appropriate. including php file inside of a jquery script just does not feel right

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with the help of a coworker, it was inputting a return character that caused the script to crash and die, we circumvented the problem by modifying the PHP so that it returned a long string literal and that fixed the problem. Sorry I took forever to get back to you guys, was away from the desk for a bit.